# Django order by inline's updated date

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two models. One of them is has a foreign key connected to other. This is my models.py:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)


    def get_absolute_url(self, ):
        return reverse('baslik', args=[self.slug])



class Entry(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    baslik = models.ForeignKey(Baslik, null=True, blank=True)
    icerik = models.TextField(max_length=50000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.icerik)
```

I used this function to show basliks that added today and that have an entry added today but it just do that, it is not sorting according time they added.
Function:

```
def hepsi(request):
    basliklar = Baslik.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-updated')
    gunlist = []
    zaman1 = date.today()
    zaman2 = str(zaman1).split(" ")
    zamangun = zaman2[0]

    for i in basliklar:
        entryler = i.entry_set.all()
        sayi2 = entryler.count()

        if sayi2>0:
            ent1 = entryler.latest('id')
            ent2 = ent1.updated
            ent3 = str(ent2).split(" ") 
            entgun = ent3[0]

            if entgun == zamangun:
                gunlist.append(i)

        if sayi2==0:
            baslik1 = i.updated
            baslik2 = str(baslik1).split(" ")
            baslikgun = baslik2[0]
            if baslikgun==zamangun:
                gunlist.append(i)

    cta = {'basliklar': basliklar, 'entryler': entryler, 'ent1': ent1, 'ent2': ent2, 'entgun': entgun, 'zamangun': zamangun, 'gunlist': gunlist, 'rast': rast}

    return render(request, "base.html", cta)
```

I want to sort the Basliks in template according to updated time of last Entry connected to them.
How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In adding entry function I added this part of code and it solved.

```
baslik.updated = entry.updated 
baslik.save()
```